# State Machine Frameworks for .NET

Tags: .net, design-patterns, frameworks, state-machine

We have a system at my work that is basically a message-driven state machine.  It takes in a variety of types of messages, looks up some context/state based on the message, then decides what to do, based on the message and the current state.  Normally the result is a message being sent out of the system.

Are there any good open-source frameworks for implementing a state machine in .NET?  I've looked into the latest release of Windows Workflow, and it seems like it would be a good option; however, I have some concerns about the default persistence mechanisms (we need to report off the state transition data), testability, and the fact that the WF team is re-architecting the framework as we speak (supposedly).

Instead of WF, I'm thinking of trying to implement a plain-old GoF "State" pattern, and using Spring.NET to wire everything together.  Is there anything out there that already does this, or something similar?

Comment: If you want a message-driven state machine, then there are a host of related issues that may be on your mind. See [What is Akka.NET](https://getakka.net/articles/intro/what-is-akka.html) and  [What problems does the actor model solve](https://getakka.net/articles/intro/what-problems-does-actor-model-solve.html). Might match your needs.

Comment: You might also be interested in a related topic [Reactive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming). For this, Akka has Reactive Streams. An alternative is [ReactiveX Observable streams](http://reactivex.io/). Be sure to investigate support for *back-pressure* in whatever technology you choose.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Depending on your exact requirements you might find the [State Machine Compiler](http://smc.sourceforge.net/) is sufficient for implementing the GoF "State" pattern. It can generate C# as well as dot which can be transformed into several image formats using [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/). I've used it on a previous project and found it sufficient for generating a 'simple' state machine. I hope this helps.

Comment: I have used SMC for C# UI code. It has worked well for me.  The state pattern is difficult to maintain over time.  SMC's DSL makes maintenance easy.

Answer (score 9):

Two great state machines for .NET

- [Stateless](https://github.com/nblumhardt/stateless) - Create state machines and lightweight state machine-based workflows directly in .NET code
- [Automatonymous](https://github.com/MassTransit/Automatonymous) - A state machine library for .Net - allows you to write fluent style state machines

Comment: I've used Stateless countless time, very easy to use and extend.  I've also used it in some very high load, low latency application.  It performed seamlessly.

Comment: New home for Stateless - https://github.com/dotnet-state-machine/stateless

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at NState

https://github.com/benaston/NState

https://nuget.org/packages/NState/.

Disclaimer: I maintain it.

Answer (score 1):

I maintain an open-source project which implements (among other things) a generic finite state machine for .NET.  It is built on top of [QuickGraph](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com), so you get many graph-analysis algorithms for free.  See [this page](http://jolt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Jolt.Automata&referringTitle=Documentation) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [StateBuilderDotNet](http://www.stateforge.com), a state machine code generator that transforms an XML description of a state machine into an extended version of the C# state pattern. It supports all UML semantics: state machine can be hierarchical, concurrent and asynchronous. A graphical tool is also available to create state machines.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of these software.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider the [North State Framework in C#](http://www.northstatesoftware.com/uml-state-machine-code-generation-framework.html).  Although it is not open source, it is relatively inexpensive to license.  It is the only framework that I know of that allows reuse through state machine composition and inheritance.  In other words, you can inherit from a base state machine with only a few lines of code, and add states, transitions, actions, etc.  You can also take an existing state machine class and "plug it into" another state machine.  You won't believe how much easier it is to implement and work with state machines using this framework, relative to GOF or other patterns.

Comment: North State Framework is now open source, with dual license option for commercial and non-commercial use.  You can find it on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

I've created [Staty](https://bitbucket.org/apacha/staty) which is a smart state-machine for .NET. Written as C# portable class library (PCL), Staty comes as an expressive event-driven state-machine with features like

- concurrence-safety
- external and interal events
- separate classes per state
- entry and exit actions and
- a fluent syntax to configure the state-machine.

It's free, open-source, available on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Staty) and based on ideas by [David Lafreniere's C++ State Machine](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/state-machine-design-in-c/184401236), which is the most famous state-machine in C++.