# Finite State Machine compiler

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, state-machine

What is the best Opensource FSM compiler which can generate c++ code ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know about the *best*, but you could look at [Ragel](http://www.complang.org/ragel/):

> Ragel compiles executable finite state machines from regular languages. Ragel targets C, C++, Objective-C, D, Java and Ruby. Ragel state machines can not only recognize byte sequences as regular expression machines do, but can also execute code at arbitrary points in the recognition of a regular language.

Answer (score 5):

Please refer to the answer I gave to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632391), [SMC](http://smc.sourceforge.net) can also generate C++ code. I can't comment on the quality of the generated C++ but for C# it's satisfactory.